# Anomaly Detection in option Theta values

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I am currently working on a financial data problem. I want to detect trades for which anomalous theta values are being generated by the models (due to several factors).

My data mainly consists of trade with its profile variables like dealId, portfolio, etc. along with different theta values along with the theta components for different dates(dates back to 3 years).
Data that I am currently using looks like this:

| Tradeid | Date1 | Date 2 and so on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1234 | 1238 |
| id2 | 1289 | 1234 |

Currently, I am Tracking daily theta movement for all trades and sending trades whose theta has moved more than 20k (absolute value).

I want to build an ML model which tracks theta movement and detects that for the current date this(or these) particular deal id/s are having anomalous theta.
So far, I have tried clustering trades based on their theta movement correlation using DBSCAN with a distance matrix. I have also tried using Isolation forest but it is not generalizing very well on the dataset.

All the examples that I have seen so far for anomaly detection are more like finding a rotten apple from a bunch of apples. Is there any algorithm that would be best suitable for my case or can be modified to best suit my problem?

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: made changes as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be too simple for the machine learning world.
You can manually define a threshold, for which the data is anomalous and identify them.

And to do that, you can easily analyze your data using pandas to find out the mean, max, min etc. and then proceed to define a threshold.